# Yii2 - Dropdownlist is selected and set value for input field

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I have this in my view (_form.php).

```
<div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#pilih_dulu").change(function(){
                    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
                            $(".box").not(".1").hide();
                            $(".1").show();
                        }

                        else if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
                            $(".box").not(".2").hide();
                            $(".2").show();
                        }

                        else if($(this).attr("value")=="3"){
                            $(".box").not(".3").hide();
                            $(".3").show();
                        }

                        else{
                            $(".box").hide();
                        }
                    });
                }).change();
            });
        </script>
    </div>

    <div class = "col-lg-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'kat_id')->label(true)->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(TblKategori::find()->all(),'kat_id','kat_kategori'), ['id' => 'pilih_dulu']
        ) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="1 box col-lg-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'sok_id')->textInput(['value' => 1]) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="2 box col-lg-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'sok_id')->textInput(['value' => 2]) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="3 box col-lg-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'sok_id')->textInput(['value' => 2]) ?>
    </div>
```

The problem is its not store the correct value. Its seems like it always store value in the last box.

Its suppose to work like this :

1. if value 1 is selected from dropdownlist, it should store value for sok_id in "1 box".
2. if value 2 is selected from dropdownlist, it should store value for sok_id in "2 box".
3. if value 3 is selected from dropdownlist, it should store value for sok_id in "3 box".

please help me. thank you

Comment: I'm not able to see any where you storing.

Comment: The process is when the dropdownlist is selected, the value is send to the change function in the <script> tag. 

For example, if value 1 is selected, div with class "1 box" is shown and the input field for sok_id is set to 1.

The problem is, the value stored for sok_id is 2 which i think from the input field in div "3 box".

sorry for my bad english. i hope you understand what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I figured out correctly you can do this, in simple way:

```
<div class = "col-lg-4">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'kat_id')->label(true)->dropDownList(
      ArrayHelper::map(TblKategori::find()->all(),'kat_id','kat_kategori'), ['id' => 'pilih_dulu', 'onchange' => 'if($(this).val() == 1) {
                        $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'sok_id').'").val($(this).val());
                    }
                    else if($(this).val() == 2) {
                        $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'sok_id').'").val($(this).val());
                    } else if($(this).val() == 3){
                        $("#'.Html::getInputId($model, 'sok_id').'").val($(this).val());
                    }'
   ']) ?>
</div>

 <div class="box col-lg-4">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'sok_id')->textInput() ?>
</div>
```

No need for 3 fields and yes add `show()` and `hide()` method where necessary.